# SQL Query to generate an extra field from data in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 fields like this sample table Tbl1

```
Person Cost FromDate
1       10  2009-1-1
1       20  2010-1-1
2       10  2009-1-1
```

I want to query it and get back the 3 fields and a generated field called ToDate that defaults to 2099-1-1 unless there is an actual ToDate implied from another entry for the person in the table.

```
select Person,Cost,FromDate,ToDate From Tbl1

Person Cost FromDate ToDate
1       10  2009-1-1 2010-1-1
1       20  2010-1-1 2099-1-1
2       10  2009-1-1 2099-1-1
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is `ToDate` a field in `Tbl1` , or something you are hoping to add to the query via a join?

Comment: no it's not in Tbl1 but I'm looking for sql code that can generate it from Tbl1 as all the data needed to work out the ToDate is in Tb11

Comment: So how is ToDate calculated from the fields in Tbl1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the minimum date from all dates that are after the record's date. If there is none you get NULL. With COALESCE you change NULL into the default date:

```
select 
  Person, 
  Cost, 
  FromDate, 
  coalesce((select min(FromDate) from Tbl1 later where later.FromDate > Tbl1.FromDate), '2099-01-01') as ToDate 
From Tbl1
order by Person, FromDate;
```

Comment: this almost works - it's just that the todate for person 2 comes back as 2010-01-01 and not the 2099-01-01 as required.

Comment: I just add the extra condition and later.Person = Tbl1.Person and that fixed everything up so many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although Thorsten's answer is perfectly fine, it would be more efficient to use window-functions to match the derived end-dates.

```
;WITH nbrdTbl 
   AS ( SELECT Person, Cost, FromDate, row_nr = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY FromDate ASC)
         FROM Tbl1)

SELECT t.Person, t.Cost, t.FromDate, derived_end_date = COALESCE(nxt.FromDate, '9991231')
  FROM nbrdTbl t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN nbrdTbl nxt
               ON nxt.Person = t.Person
              AND nxt.row_nr = t.row_nr + 1
ORDER BY t.Person, t.FromDate
```

Doing a test on a 2000-records table it's about 3 times as efficient according to the Execution plan (78% vs 22%).